# A command to add data into another json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord, discord.js

actually I've a json file test.json with information like this:

```
{
"id": ["1234"]
}
```

Now I want to add another id 2345 using discord.js. I am actually saving user ids in json file and now I want to make a command that will push more ids into the test.json file.

For example: With that command i can add another userid "2345" so that the json file will look like this:

```
{
"id": ["1234", "2345"]
}
```

Please Help me regarding this!!

Comment: If `const jsObj = { "id": ["1234"]};` is a variable, then `jsObj.id.push("2345");` will add `"2345"` to it and make it: `{ "id": ["1234", "2345"]}`. FWIW.

Comment: The steps are, 1) read the file, 2) parse the data, 3) process the data, 4) serialize the data, 5) write the file. There is no built-in command to add a value to a JSON file.

Comment: it's not even related to discord.js

Comment: If your question is not related to a topic, then don't add the topic tag to your question. In this case, since your question is not related to `discord.js`, there was no need to add the tag for it

Answer (score 0):

There are several options below, all of which will have to be worked further to achieve the exact result you need but this will get you pointed in the right direction.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const cName = './path_to_json_from_bot_root_folder.json';

function requireUncached(module) {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
    return require(module);
}

let file;
setInterval(() => {
    file = requireUncached('../../path_to_json_from_this_file.json');
}, 500);

function prep(file) {
    const myJson = JSON.stringify(file);
    const JsonCut = myJson.slice(0, myJson.length - 1);
    return JsonCut;
}
// Option 1
fs.writeFile(cName, 'information to input will completely overwrite the file', { format: 'json', }), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});

// Option 2
fs.writeFile(cName, prep(file) + 'add new information here will have to work through it to make sure that you have all the closing brackets' + '}', { format: 'json', }), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});

// Option 3
const oldInfo = file['subsectionName']
const newInfo = message.content // or whatever method you choose like args if you make it a command
fs.writeFile(cName, prep(file) + ${JSON.stringify(file['subsectionName']).trim().replace(`${oldInfo}`, `${newInfo}` + '}', { format: 'json', }), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Its saying cannot read the property of slice, i tried the second one

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using